# Dynamically created custom listview issue

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio, android-listview

We are working on a project where there is a questionnaire section.The questions and its options are dynamically generated.For testing we created a main class and a custom adapter.Within the adapter we have tried to create the radio button dynamically.**The issue is that on scrolling the listview the options get duplicated or get merged**.Why is this happening.I have shown the code below.

The main class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    CustomAdapter cadp;
    ListView list_questions;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        list_questions= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_question);
        cadp=new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this);
        list_questions.setAdapter(cadp);


    }

}
```

The custom adapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    SingleHolder sh;



    public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context=context;
        inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 10;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_choice_layout, null);
            sh = new SingleHolder();
            sh.single_question_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.single_question_name);
            sh.single_radiogroup = (RadioGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.single_radiogroup);
            convertView.setTag(sh);

        }
        else
        {
            sh = (SingleHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        sh.single_question_name.setText("question name");

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(convertView.getContext());
            rb.setText("value");
            sh.single_radiogroup.addView(rb);
        }


        return convertView;
    }
    private   class SingleHolder
    {
        TextView single_question_name;
        RadioGroup single_radiogroup;
    }
}
```

Single list element layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/single_question_name"
        />
    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/single_radiogroup"
        android:orientation="vertical"></RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: set j values as a tag on rb and get its on click then check it on answer list

Comment: there is other way also.if you know that every question will have only 3 answers then make 3  RadioButton in layout file. and when creating the adapter take reference of all and set answer as a tag and get that on any event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The issue is that on scrolling the listview the options get duplicated
>   or get merged

Here:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
  {
    RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(convertView.getContext());
    rb.setText("value");
    sh.single_radiogroup.addView(rb);
  }
```

these lines causing issue because when `convertView is not equals to null` means `RadioButton's` in  `single_radiogroup` is already avalible no need to add it again.

Add `RadioButton` when `convertView is null`:

```
 if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_choice_layout, null);
            sh = new SingleHolder();
           ....
         // add RadioButton here
        }
        else
        {
            sh = (SingleHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
```

**EDIT:**

As per your requirement remove old view from RadioGroup before adding new:

```
sh.single_radiogroup.clearCheck();
sh.single_radiogroup.removeAllViews();
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
   {
      RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(convertView.getContext());
      rb.setText("value");
      sh.single_radiogroup.addView(rb);
   }
```

Comment: Actually we want the radio buttons to be generated dynamically we have just set the loop for 3 times for testing.The number of times the radio button would be created would be dynamic based on a value from a list passed from the main class.If we give the for loop within if (convertView==null) it would run only once and would not work for subsequent positions of the list.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because you are directly modifying the "convertView" which is passed to "getView" method.

Try to hold that "convertView" in a variable and perform "setTag" & "getTag" operations on that variable.

Here is the link how to do this(This is Xamarin android code, I hope this is useeful)

https://blog.xamarin.com/creating-highly-performant-smooth-scrolling-android-listviews/

And there is a facility in xamarin that we can generate listview with radio & checkbox for selection.
Is this helpful to you. Please check out this link once

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/part_3_-_customizing_a_listview's_appearance/